# Flutter web App deployed via GitHub actions shows wrong app

Tags: flutter, web, github-actions, github-pages

I have a Flutter App As my User-GH Pages.
I tried to add another flutter web app as a  project-gh pages. (Via manual GitHub actions workflow)

sensn.github.io

sensn.github.io/particle_field

Problem: both pages load the same flutter web app 1 which is supposed to be only on the user-GH page. I think it's a problem with Caching but don't know how to fix.

I was expecting the project GH page to show the particle field app.

Instead it shows My App from user GH Page

Main.yml from project-pahe repo:

```
name: particle_field
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build Web
    env:
      my_secret: ${{secrets.Commit_secret}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          channel: 'master'
      - run: |
             cd example    
             flutter config --enable-web
             flutter pub get
             flutter build web --release
      - run: |
          cd example/build/web
          git init
          # type configurations: your user.email and user.name followed lines 
          # git config --global user.email your_email 
          # git config --global user.name your_name 
          git config --global user.email ***
          git config --global user.name ***
          git status
          # change this remote url for examle your remote url is https://github.com/onatcipli/particle_field.git then the following:
          git remote add origin https://${{secrets.Commit_secret}}@github.com/sensn/particle_field.git
          git checkout -b gh-pages
          git add --all
          git commit -m "update"
          git push origin gh-pages -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had to set the base href in main.yml

flutter build web --release --base-href '/particle_field/'